# (Strengthened) Caratheodory's Theorem

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-hulls

Consider a function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ where $X$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Consider the set $$ S = \{ (x,f(x))\vert x \in X \}$$ According to Caratheodory's Theorem, any point in the convex hull of $S$ can be represented as a convex combination of three points in $S$ because $S \in \mathbb{R}^2$. But I feel that two points are enough (or maybe I missed some specific shape of the curve). Am I right? Does it have anything to do with the "dimension" of $S$ itself? (I feel that $S$ is "one-dimension", but I don't know how to precisely describe this.)

Thank @David Mitra for the counterexample. I feel that the argument fails because some interior points need more elements to be involved in the convex combination. So how about only considering points on the boundary? Formally,

$T(x) = \sup \{y \vert (x,y)\in co\{S\}\}$, where $\sup$ means supremum and co means convex hull. And $T=\{(x, T(x)\vert x \in X)\}$. Intuitively, $T$ is the "ceiling" of the convex hull of $S$. Is it true that every point in $T$ can be represented as a convex combination of two points in $S$?

Comment: $f(x)=1$, $x=0$; $f(x)=0$, otherwise. $(0,1/2)$ is in the convex hull.

Comment: You can if $f$ is continuous, I think. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3526783/convex-hull-of-path-in-mathbb-r2-is-the-set-of-convex-combination-of-2-point).

Comment: @DavidMitra What is the $X$ in your example?

Comment: $[-1,1]$. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks for the clarification. I adjusted the conjecture accordingly.